# Set var to true/false in toggle function

Tags: jquery, boolean, toggle

I have a button and I want my variable `click` to be set to `true` when the button is clicked, and `false` when the button is clicked again (I want toggle functionality).

When `click == true`, I want it to output `clicked` into the console and when `click == false` I want it to output `not clicked`.

```
var click = false
```

Here's my toggle function:

```
$('.button').toggle(
    function(){
        click = true;
        $('.bmw').show();

    }, function() {
        click = false;
        $('.bmw').hide();

    });
```

And what I want it to do:

```
if(click = true) {
    console.log('clicked');
} else {
    console.log('not clicked');
}
```

When I load the page the console shows `not clicked` but when I press the button it doesn't switch to `true`. The bmw objects** `.bmw` do however show and hide when I toggle the button so that seems to be working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning not comparing the value of click

You should be doing this with `==` not `=`

```
if(click == true) {
    console.log('clicked');
} else {
    console.log('not clicked');
}
```

However you do not even need to use `if(click == true)`.  You can in fact just use `if(click)` instead.

EDIT:  From what we discussed in the comments it looks like you were calling the if statement only once when the code was first run, not everytime you toggled.  I suggest creating a seperate function with the if statement inside, then calling this method in both parts of the toggle.

Comment: This may not be your only problem however it is a problem in your code.  Once you fix and test this you will be able to see if there are other problems with your code.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. So I tried that and unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the only problem.. it still doesn't work. Thanks though!

Comment: Where do you have your if statement? When is it called?  Are you actually calling it everytime you toggle?

Comment: Do I have to call it everytime I toggle? I didn't know that. Right now I'm calling it after the toggle function. So am I supposed to move it into the toggle function?

Comment: @KristinaSaskia Yes you will need to call it everytime you toggle since it is a check to see if the variable is at this moment true or false.  I would create a seperate function witht he if statement in and call this from within the toggle.

Comment: I see. Do I call it twice in the toggle (for both clicked and unclicked)?

Comment: Yes you will need to call it once in each section of the toggle.

Comment: @KristinaSaskia great, I will edit my answer slightly to add what we discussed.  If it fixed your problem just click the accept next tot he answer.