# boolean if and else statement to toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, boolean-logic, togglebutton

I am receiving a True/False statement called favIcon, that is responsible for a button state. This button toggles from "active to "disabled", and behaves similar to a "facebook like button": on page load, if favIcon is true it shows the button "Active".

First thing I am trying to do is to console.log the favState condition with an If statement. Current attempt looks like this ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393935/boolean-in-an-if-statement) is my reference):

```
     var favIcon = true;

     function onload(){
       if(favIcon == true){
            console.log ("active");
       }

       else {
             console.log ("disabled"); 
       }}
```

I didn't manage to make it work, and once I have this response, it will allow me to go to the next step:

if favIcon == true, button state is active

if favIcon == false, button state is disabled

Now the button goes from disabled to active (I managed to make something to work!) (used this for [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432369/set-var-to-true-false-in-toggle-function))

```
     <input id="button" type="button" value="disabled">

     <script>
             $('#button').click(function() {
             $(this).val('active');
         });
     </script>
```

Hopefully I was clear enough. Thank you all.

Comment: To make this question clearer you might consider providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Where is the `onload` function called?

Comment: Where is your `onload()` function being called from?

Comment: are you missing one closing bracket in onLoad function? And from where is it called?

Comment: I am calling from <body onload="foo()"> is this right? tks

Comment: Now the closing bracket is just at the wrong place, it needs to be "after" the `else` part. Also, `onLoad()` won't be called from `<body onload="foo()">`. A function named `foo` if exists, will be called.

Comment: as Vandesh say, you don't have the onload function well balanced.

Comment: oh, I see. Do you think it would be better to check the button "value" rather than doing onpage load? . tks @Vandesh

Comment: If you only want to diable/enable the button based on favIcon value you can do it using .prop(). Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the button based on `favIcon` value as follows -

```
$("#button").prop("disabled",favIcon);
```

And to run the above code, wrap it inside document ready like -

```
$(function(){
  $("#button").prop("disabled",favIcon);
});
```

More on [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)